# How do you add to, append to or extend a YAML sequence?

Tags: yaml

If you have:

```
bananas:
  foobar: &foobar_seq_bananas
  - source: lorem
  - source: ipsum
  - source: dolor
apples:
  foobar: 
  ???? *foobar_seq_bananas
  - source: 1000
```

What syntax do you use in apples / foobar in order to add an item to the referenced sequence?

I tried this syntax:

```
bananas:
  foobar: &foobar_seq_bananas
  - source: lorem
  - source: ipsum
  - source: dolor
apples:
  foobar:
   - *foobar_seq_bananas
   - source: 1000
```

But it produces a list of lists:

```
apples: 
  foobar: 
    - 
      - 
        source: lorem
      - 
        source: ipsum
      - 
        source: dolor
    - 
      source: 1000
```

The desired outcome would be a single (flat) list under `apples/foobar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YAML is not a programming language and generally does not provide you with operators of any kind.

An exception is the [merge key](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html) specified for outdated YAML 1.1, which is not part of the spec but supported by some implementations. However, that is for merging mappings, not sequences.

If you want to replicate items in multiple places in your YAML, your best bet is to use some templating language (popular with YAML is Jinja2, used e.g. in Ansible and SaltStack). The loading code must be aware that you use a templating language, and if not, you must manually preprocess your YAML with the templating language before giving it to the loading code.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up going with this:

```
apples:
  foobar:
   - *foobar_seq_bananas
   - source: 1000
```

And in the consuming script post-processed with flattening logic:

```
    flat_list = []
    for obj in yaml_json:
        if isinstance(obj, list):
            flat_list += obj
        else:
            flat_list.append(obj)
```